# Assistance required for calculating algorithmic complexity - CSc fundamentals

Tags: complexity-theory

Hi I have two algorithms that need their complexity worked out, i've had a try myself at first; O(N^2) & O(N^3) Here they are:

Treat Y as though it's declared 'y=int[N][N]' and B as though 'B=int[N][N]'....

```
int x(int [] [] y)
{
int z = 0
for (int i =0; i<y.length; i++)
    z = z + y[i].length;
  return z;
}

int A (int [] [] B)
{
    int c =0
    for ( int i =0; i<B.length; i++)
        for (int j =0; j<B[i].length; j++)
             C = C + B[i] [j];
    return C;
}
```

Thanks alot :)

Comment: What are the complexities? is O(n^2) and O(n^3) right??

Comment: Well, the first one's a bit odd, but those time complexities look right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To caclulate the algorithmic complexity, you need to tally up the number of operations performed in the algorithm (the big-O notation is concerned about worst case scenario)

In the first case, you have a loop that is performed N times (y.length==N).  Inside the loop you have one operation (executed on each iteration).  This is linear in the number of inputs, so O(x)=N.

*Note*: calculating y[i].length is a constant length operation.

In the second case, you have the outer loop that is performed N times (just like in the first case), and in each iteration another loop if the same length (N==B[i].length) is executed.  Inside the inner loop you have one operation (executed on each iteration of the inner loop).  This is O(N*N)==O(N^2) overall.

*Note*: calculating b[i][j] is a constant length operation

*Note*: remember that for big-O, only the fastest-growing term matters, so additive constants can be ignored (e.g. the initialization of the return value and the return instruction are both operations, but are constants and not executed in a loop; the term depending on N grows faster than constant)